# Remove the white line beneath a control in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, line, styling, scenebuilder

[image: Styling]

How do I remove that annoying little white line beneath the progress bar (and make it dark or light blue)? The checkbox and the buttons have the same white line, but they should be blue!

I've set:

```
-fx-text-box-border: #284a81;
-fx-control-inner-background: #284a81;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the `-fx-shadow-highlight-color` invisible:

```css
.progress-bar {
    -fx-text-box-border: #284a81;
    -fx-control-inner-background: #284a81;
    -fx-shadow-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```